# seam-cron , @Expiration and @IntervalCron?

Tags: cron, quartz-scheduler, seam3

I was migrating my project from **seam 2** to **seam 3** .

In seam 2 we have `@Expiration` and `@IntervalCron` annotations but in **seam-cron** we don't have any such annotations. `@scheduled` is there but it's incomplete for my requirement.

I have gone through documentation but coudn't find any luck.

Is there any way to handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't recommend to use Seam Cron, because the project is inactive and there won't be releases anymore. At least as far as I know.

So currently I recommend to use the scheduling functionality of EJB3 instead.

I'm not aware of any other CDI extension to provide such functionality.

Answer (score 0):

The EJB3 schedule/timer/asynchronous is problematic when use the dependent EJB as CDI bean.

You can consider write a CDI extension for Cron like scheduling using Quartz, jaxenter.com provides an excellent tutorial for this.

http://jaxenter.com/tension-programming-42972.html